# How to get invitable_friends list from facebook using graph API

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I want to get invitable_friends from facebook.While using the this code:-

```
new GraphRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            "/me/invitable_friends",null,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new GraphRequest.Callback()
            {
               @Override
               public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response)
               {
                /* Handle the result */
                System.out.println("=========================");
                System.out.println("==>> :" + response);
                System.out.println("=========================");
               }
}).executeAsync();
```

I am getting this error

```
Response: responseCode: 400, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 100, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#100) No permission to access invitable_friends
```

Can any one please tell me how to set invitable_friends permission and how can I get invitable_friends list.

Thanks in Advance..!!

Comment: is your app a game with canvas implementation?

Comment: No, its just a simple app.

Answer (score 0):

> This feature is only available to games with a presence on Facebook Desktop

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/gamerequests#invitablefriends

You can only use this for games with a Canvas implemenation.

How to invite friends to a non-game App is explained in the FAQ: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq

Comment: Can you please tell me how to create a game with canvas presence ?

Comment: that is quite a broad question. you can create a game with html/javascript/php/whatever. what game would it be? there are lots of books and tutorials about how to create games.

Comment: Okay, but can you please tell me how can I connect my game with facebook to invite friends? while selecting platform which will I have to select "Android" or "Facebook Canvas"

Comment: i thought that your app is NOT a game? you can´t just try to circumvent this, only use invitable_friends for games.

Comment: Canvas is a web platform, so you would have to code a whole new version of your game, if you want to use canvas. (You are only allowed to use canvas and invitable_friends, if you have a _playable_ version of your game on canvas.) You might perhaps rather want to look into https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/android